# In what files in the home dir does xfce store the user config data?

Tags: linux, backup, restore, xfce

In what files/dirs in the home dir does xfce store the user config data?

Or if you like.

What files do I need to restore from backup in order to restore my xfce desktop with all the different settings I made?

Thanks Johan

---

*Edit*: 
All user config files is usually stored somewhere in /home/$USER/.
And since all the programs, kde, xfce and gnome stores their config there, this question is about what files belong to the xfce desktop.

---

This is my guess of what files belong to the xfce desktop:

- .config/Thunar/
- .config/xfce4/
- .config/xfce4-session/
- .config/user-dirs.dirs
- .config/user-dirs.locale
- .cache/Thunar/
- .cache/xfce4/
- .cache/sessions/

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtually all Linux programs store their info in either .< program name >or ./config/< ProgramName >